# Failed to re-initialize metastore

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

**Update2**
I abandoned my idea about downgrade the hive metastore. It's not supported by schemetool by default if you check the help information of it. Leave this thread here to remind later visitors:

1. When you can't init schema of `mysql metastore` for `hive`, it's probably because the version of current hive binary is different from the binary which you used to initialize `metastore` the first time.
2. It's not a good idea to downgrade the hive metastore. Maybe you should stick to higher version hive.

**Update1** 
I found the issue might be with the inconsistent version of `Hive`.
I installed `Hive` 3.x at first and also initialized the metastore.
currently, I need to downgrade Hive from 3.x to 2.x for some unavoidable reason. 
So the question turns to how can I downgrade Hive installation (majorly about how to reinitialize `Hive metastore` from 3.x to 2.x)

**Original**
I'm using `Mysql` as `Hive` metastore.
I tried to reinitialize the metastore by `schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema --verbose`, however, I met error below:

```
Error: Duplicate key name 'PCS_STATS_IDX' (state=42000,code=1061)
Closing: 0: jdbc:mysql://10.1.2.209:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
Underlying cause: java.io.IOException : Schema script failed, errorcode 2
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:590)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:563)
```

Existed solution on SO is about `derby` database, any idea about how to handle this issue with `mysql` database?

Comment: Hey Eugene, have you figured out a solution for this?

Comment: @BrunoBraga Hi Bruno, if I remembered it correctly, I just remove everything regarding Hive and reinstalled it on my environment.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and as the comment by Bruno said, I remove everything regarding Hive, and it's okay again.

Here is  What I do is log into the mysql, and delete the database:

```
drop database hive;
```

You don't need to drop the database user.

then you recreate the database.